# removing index.php from URL

Tags: debian, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I am running a wordpress site with Astra theme.

I use the custom permalinks and I would like to remove index.php from url.

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress                                                                                                                                                                                          
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are                                                                                                                                 
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.                                                                                                                                
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.                                                                                                                                 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                                                                                   
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                           
RewriteBase /                                                                                                                                                                                              
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]                                                                                                                                                                             
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                                                                        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                                                                        
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]                                                                                                                                                                               
</IfModule>                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# END WordPress
```

At this point, if I still have index.php in my URL, I think that the .htaccess file is ignored by apache. This is my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf setting:

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All

  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All is granted and I can do whatever garbage in my .htaccess file, it does nothing.

I put garbage also in the Directory directive in apache2.conf but still nothing changed.

My Module rewrite is already enabled.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check your config for the directive [`AccessFileName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#accessfilename).

Comment: Also make sure there isn't another `AllowOverride` directive in your config in a `Location` block that overrides the `Directory` block.

Comment: Another thing to check is if `mod_rewrite` is enabled. As long as you only modify the part between the `<IfModule>` tags, it will be ignored if the module is not loaded.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Check your WordPress configuration.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after putting “garbage” in the `Directory` directive?

Comment: I have no AllowOverride directive in my config other than the one in Directory, and yes I restarted apache each time I changed the config

Comment: Is this issue resolved?  If yes, can you help me with this?